# Avoid 'for without next' End Sub

Tags: excel, vba

It would be very helpfully if some of the experts here help me with the problem:
I have a loop to check zero values in range and the problem is I cant avoid the error 'for without next'. Maybe this is wrong construction for the for loop using End Sub ? Thank you.

```
For Each c In Range("B4:H4")

     If c.Value = 0 Then MsgBox "Wrong record!", vbExclamation
     End Sub
Next c
```

Answer (score 5):

Exit, not end.

```
For Each c In Range("B4:H4")

  If c.Value = 0 Then 
    MsgBox "Wrong record!", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
  End If
Next c
```

However, it is generally best to work out a way to limit the number of points to exit.